# How to separate the first word in a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I have the following code:

```
<center>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
    <span style="color: #ff000a; text-align: center;">
        <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
    </span>
</a>
```

`the_title();` will show me a name and a surname.

I want to separate `the_title();` to show just the first word, so just the first name and not the surname.

Tried everything but I haven't achieved anything.

Comment: Looks like Wordpress, bleeech!

Comment: You can use like user data firstname like: `$user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
      $first_name = $user_info->first_name;`

Comment: @Abra Too bad that `the_*` functions just `echo` directly…

Comment: @deceze: Unless you pass `false` as 3rd arg.

Comment: @Abra Ah, okay, as far as I remembered (*shudder*) there were separate `get_the_*` functions for that. But then again… Wordpress is not my thing.

Comment: @Abra Though `echo explode(...)` will give *Array to string conversion* notice… ;)

Comment: @deceze Sometimes it's an `echo` or `return` argument on [`the_*`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/). Sometimes it's [`get_*`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/). Sometimes it's [`get_the_*`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content). Fun times!

Comment: `echo explode(' ', the_title('', '', false))[0];`

Comment: @deceze: Forgot the `[0]`

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for trying to help me out.

the code I copy-pasted as it is, it already print a name and a surname so

when the code is executed I get let's say *  Barack Obama *

I am trying to show the first name Barack before that < span style=""></span> and then The surename in the <span

Hopefully, i was more clear with my issue.

As you have understood my knowledge is less than a beginner, so thank you for even trying to teach something to me :).

@AbraCadaver

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, because your code did the trick :) 

- echo explode(' ', the_title('', '', false))[0];

Comment: You should accept an answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out you probably want `get_the_title` instead as it returns data instead of echoing it.  `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`:

```
list($first, $last) = explode(' ', get_the_title());
<?=$first ?>
<span style="color: #ff000a; text-align: center;">
    <strong><?=$last ?></strong>
</span>
```

If `get_the_title` doesn't work for some reason then pass `false` so that data is returned and not echoed:

```
list($first, $last) = explode(' ', the_title('', '', false));
```

Also this works to just output the first name:

```
echo explode(' ', the_title('', '', false))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve yor title first. Use [get_the_title();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) for this or [the_title();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) **!important** in `the_title()` you should set first and second parameters as empty string and 3rd parameter as false, like this -  `the_title('', '', false);` But i`m recommend use get_the_title() for you. Then you need separate your string to parts with words. Function [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will help you.

Se an example:

```
// exmplate title = 'John Smith';
$words = explode(' ', get_the_title());
print_r($words); // will print array like this:
array( 
  0 => 'John',
  1 => 'Smith',
)
```

Comment: Might explain.  They may not know the difference between `get_the_title()` and `the_title()` etc...

Comment: `get_the_title()` - return in PHP title text without any wrappers or something. the_title print title, wrapped in 1 and 2 arguments, if they are declared. But if set false in 3rd arg - `the_title()` - will also return it to PHP. For getting title in PHP and next usage  `get_the_title()` - recommended.

Comment: I know.  You might edit that into your post for the OP.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks. But you can edit my answer and add your wishes. I`m will be glad to apply useful fixes. Anyway - thanks!